# The $R^x$ notation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am repeating some linear algebra and I can't remember how to read statemeents like this:

$$ T: R^4  \rightarrow R^2 $$

There is a transformation of some sort, right? But What does the 4 and the 2 stands for?

Comment: I think it denotes the dimension of the space. So $R^4$ means $\mathbb{R}^4=\{(x,y,z,t)|x,y,z,t\in \mathbb {R}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess $R$ is your field of the real numbers. So $R^n$ is vector space of all vectors with $n$ components, in which every component is a real value. For Example: $$\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\4\end{pmatrix}\in R^3$$. Thus 4 and 2 stands for the dimension of your vector space.

$T$ is now a function, which has a 4-dimensional vector as input and makes a 2-dimensional vector out of that. For Example:
$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

In linear algebra this is mostly done by an matrix. For Example:

$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\\4\\6\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

They stand for the dimension of the coordinate system. For example, $R^3$ is the 3-dimensional coordinate system containing points with coordinates of x, y, and z. $R^2$ is the coordinate system you used when learning middle school algebra, with just the x and y axes. $R^4$ doesn't have a geometric meaning to us, but it just contains a fourth coordinate for every point; imagine w, x, y, and z.

Comment: And of course, just like the usual rules of exponentiation, $\mathbb R^1$ is $\mathbb R$ itself, the real line. Fun exercise: What is $\mathbb R^0$?

Comment: @Rahul: If $0\in\mathbb{N}$ then $\mathbb{R}$ gets a valuable meaning. :D

Answer (score 0):

In a more general context $R^{A}$ usually stands for the set of functions
with domain $A$ and codomain $R$.

This demands $A$ to be a set
and e.g. number $4$ can be interpreted as set $\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} $.

Then functions $\left\{ 0,1,2,3\right\} \rightarrow R$ can be looked
at as tuples $\left(r_{0},r_{1},r_{2},r_{3}\right)$ with $r_{i}\in R$
for $i=0,1,2,3$.